# Fonts needed for browsers

Tags: fonts, unicode, browser

I'm having this issue where many unicode symbols aren't displayed(just boxes instead) on websites.
But aren't they supposed to be loaded(by the browser) from external sources? 
If not, what fonts do I need to get so I'd have no trouble with that?

My setup: Gentoo + dwm + Google Chrome

Update:
No extensions are used.
E.g., [hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen) isn't displayed.
[fc-list output](https://0bin.net/paste/RgA0ez2xFm4vpFRI#vKNYJtcj5rPBRl3-Dz2YtAapZO4vEFfCibC3eMNf6xv)

Comment: Do you have [uBlock origin](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock) (for example) installed as an extension in your browser? It has an option to block remote fonts or to allow them. As for installing fonts, upload the output of `fc-list` somewhere so that people don't suggest fonts you already have. And specific examples of websites would help.

Comment: Do you have a specific example of a glyph/website that doesn't work?

Comment: I had a similar issue and installing media-fonts/noto fixed it for me.